# How to get engineering multiples notation out of numerica results

Tags: siunitx, physics, scientific-notation

The numerica package is a very handy tool to solve circuit equations, but I couldn't find a way to get numerical results using engineering multiples like mA, kV, etc. The siunitx package has a very nice solution as follows, but I couldn't get both packages in a pipeline because the macro expansion is not a simple text result initially.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage{physics} % before numerica!!!
\usepackage{numerica} % computation of math expressions
\def\eval{\nmcEvaluate} % to simplify numerica avoiding conflict with physics
\usepackage{siunitx}
% --- siunitx settings -----
\sisetup {
    exponent-to-prefix  = true,       % convert exponents into belonging prefixes
    round-mode          = places,
    round-precision     = 2,
    scientific-notation = engineering,% try to use next engineering unit instead of '.'
    per-mode            = symbol,
    per-symbol          = /
}% --------------------------

\begin{document}

Numerica is used to solve the Ohm's Law $I_B = VCC/R1$, given $R1= \SI{10}{\kilo\ohm}$ and $VCC= \SI{5}{\volt}$  as follows: \eval[vv=, eq=\approx]{$I_B$}[I_B = VCC/R1, R1=10^4,  VCC=5.0][2x] A.

However, the result uses scientific notation instead of engineering multiples notation that is nicely provided by siunitx as follows: $ V_B \approx \num{5e-4}$A, or even better in a compact form \SI{5e-4}{\ampere}.

I tried a naive approach to mix the two packages siunitx and numerica but it doesn't work.
% \SI{\eval[vv=, eq=\approx]{$I_B$}[I_B = VCC/R1, R1=10^4,  VCC=5.0][2x]}{\ampere}

\end{document} '''
```

Comment: Anisio you get the problem, as  `numerica` returns the typeset equation, whereas `SI` expects a number.  I am not too sure if it is solvable, as looking into some of the `numerica` code it seems to use regexes for transformations. Anyway as an engineer I suggest, if you have similar problems is to move onto LuaLaTeX, separating the calculation from the display and always make unit convertions as the last step. I.e., all input must be at the units expected by the equation.

Comment: @yannis LuaLatex is an option and Lua, another language to grasp! It's sad because the numerica package has a neat text code!

Comment: True, numerica is an amazing library. Never used it, but looked at the manual and is very impressive. But I see maybe the solution below by the developer can fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present the only way I can see to achieve the desired result is to use `numerica`'s `\reuse` command which saves the result of a calculation to a macro (which is then available for use elsewhere in the current document and also saved to file; see section 6.4 of the `numerica` manual). I've chosen `ohmslaw` as the name of the macro:

````
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage{physics} % before numerica!!!
\usepackage{numerica} % computation of math expressions
\def\eval{\nmcEvaluate} % to simplify numerica avoiding conflict with physics
\usepackage{siunitx}
% --- siunitx settings -----
\sisetup {
    exponent-to-prefix  = true,       % convert exponents into belonging prefixes
    round-mode          = places,
    round-precision     = 2,
    scientific-notation = engineering,% try to use next engineering unit instead of '.'
    per-mode            = symbol,
    per-symbol          = /
}% --------------------------

\begin{document}

\eval[vv=, eq=\approx]{$I_B$}[I_B = VCC/R1, R1=10^4,  VCC=5.0][5] A.
\reuse[renew]{ohmslaw}

\SI{\ohmslaw}{\ampere}.

\end{document} '''

Note that I saved the calculated result in ordinary decimal notation rather than scientific notation (the 5 rather than your 2x in the trailing number format option of ```\eval```).
````